# Accessing index of an array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase

i am building a simple React app where i collect data from a Firebase realtime database and push it as an array (memberArr) into the component state via setState:

```
this.setState({members: memberArr})
```

When I log the state in the render() method, I see the contents of the array. In the React Dev Tools the state is also filled as expected.

If I now want to access the contents of the array (e.g. with this.state.members[0]) the console returns undefined.

I initialize the state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      members: [],
  };
}
```

My whole componentDidMount() method looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const membersRef = firebase.database().ref(`${groupName}/members`);

    membersRef.on('value', (data) => {

      const memberArr = []; 

      data.forEach(function(snapshot){

        //Gets name of member
        var memberName = snapshot.val().name;

        //Gets UID of member
        var memberKey = snapshot.key;

        //Get expenses from fetched member. When ready call function to push everything as array into component state.
        this.getExpensesFromUser(memberKey).then(function(data) {
          pushArray(data)
        });

        function pushArray(memberExpense) {
          memberArr.push([memberName, memberKey, memberExpense])
        };

        //This works:
        //memberArr.push([memberName, memberKey])

      }.bind(this));

      this.setState({members: memberArr})

    });
  }
```

On a side note: If I avoid calling

```
this.getExpensesFromUser(memberKey).then(function(data) {
          pushArray(data)
        });
```

and only use the following to push the name and key of the members:

```
memberArr.push([memberName, memberKey])
```

everything works as expected. console.log(this.state.members[0][0]) returns the name of the first member after the render() method gets triggered due to setState.

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: Check the array is filled before map through it at render.

Comment: `this.getExpensesFromUser(memberKey)` is async and you're setting the state before actually receiving the values, so your state is always []

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu But why am I seeing the correct content oft the state in the React Dev Tools? Moreover: If I console.log the state inside the render() method it also shows me the content I expect.

Comment: instead of `pushArray(data)` in the `.then(data)` try doing `this.setState({members: [...this.state.members, data]`

Comment: I think that initialization has not finished yet. My opinion is to use constructor to initialie state and then fill its data either @ your contructor or you componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dragos commented, your `getExpensesFromUser` function returns asynchronous results, so you need to make sure to only call `setState` once those calls have finished.

```
const membersRef = firebase.database().ref(`${groupName}/members`);
membersRef.on('value', (data) => {
  const promises = [];
  data.forEach((snapshot) => {
    var memberKey = snapshot.key;
    promises.push(this.getExpensesFromUser(memberKey))
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    const memberArr = data.map((item) => [memberName, memberKey, memberExpense]);
    this.setState({members: memberArr})
  });
});
```